# The wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default

Tags: pallet, wasm

I'm attempting to implement a custom pallet, but I keep running into this compile error:

```rs
error: the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.7/src/lib.rs:235:9
      |
  235 | /         compile_error!("the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by \
  236 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  237 | |                         For more information see: \
  238 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.7/src/lib.rs:262:5
      |
  262 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
      |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
```

I have found a few other posts related to this but I haven't found an answer with a connection to the pallets. If I omit the custom pallet, then everything builds fine. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Fyi if you want to compile the runtime dir directly then `cargo check --target=wasm32-unknown-unknoun --no-default-features` gets rid of the js error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pallets compile to WASM which means that all dependencies need to work in a *no-std* environment.
In your case it looks like one of your dependencies tries to generate random numbers.
This does not work in WASM and the dependency therefore prints that it cannot build.
There are a few cases where this can easily be fixed:

- Add the dependency as *dev* dependency if you only need it in tests.
- Use the [proper way](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/121/secure-random-number-generation) to generate randomness on-chain.
- Use `cargo tree` to find out how the randomness dependency ends up in your pallet if you don't intend to use it.
- Analyze the offending dependency and see if it even supports *no-std*.

In any way; it always helps if you share the code. But hopefully this gives you a hint!

Comment: It turns out that I had a dependency spelt incorrectly. I had looked through the entire tree searching for the problem and couldn't find it. If anyone is coming across a similar problem make sure that the dependancies are correctly implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved the same issue. In my case it was an extra dependency in a custom pallet.
After removing `frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", path = "../../frame/benchmarking" }` from Cargo.toml it compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your newly added substrate dependency have `default-features = false`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your std configuration is correct.

Take a look at https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10837. You may need to cherry-pick this one.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Cargo.lock file and changing `optional = true` to `false` in Cargo.toml `frame-benchmarking`'s entry worked for me.