# error: the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by default

Tags: pallet, nft

I have been trying to implement `pallet-nft-fractionalization` with the `substrate-node-template`, Since `pallet-nft-fractionalization` was released in the last few months had to change the branch of all the pallets to `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.43"` despite doing all the changes, I'm still facing the issue that is ::

```
    error: the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /Users/XXXXXX/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.10/src/lib.rs:285:9
      |
  285 | /         compile_error!("the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by \
  286 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  287 | |                         For more information see: \
  288 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /Users/XXXXXX/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.10/src/lib.rs:341:9
      |
  341 |         imp::getrandom_inner(dest)?;
      |         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
  error: could not compile `getrandom` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
```

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while any help would be welcomed :)

Comment: try checking if you are setting all you pallet imports  as default-features to false. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/the-wasm32-unknown-unknown-target-is-not-supported-by-default?rq=1

Comment: @Xavier Yes all of my pallets imports are set to `default-features = false`

Comment: Please install `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`

Comment: would be useful to also show your cargo.toml file for the runtime in your question

Comment: As suggested would be great if you can show a bit more of your code for us to try to replicate it

Answer (score 3):

It was a bit tricky to find a solution, thanks to the parity team member who helped with this problem.

When working with `pallet-nft-fractionalization` which is available only after `v0.9.43`.we would have to upgrade the runtime of the node to version `v0.9.43`. Along with that, we would have to make minor runtime changes, which can be found in this PR: https://github.com/sacha-l/substrate-nfts-node/pull/4/files if you would like to get a basic template for NFT + fractionalization, you can use https://github.com/sacha-l/substrate-nfts-node/ repo to get started.