# How to generate random number of a specific length in Substrate pallet

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, random, randomness

I want to generate random number of a specific length. I can't use `insecure-randomness-collective-flip` because it's not recommended for production.

I also can't use `rand` package because it doesn't support `no_std`.

Is there any way or library which I can use to generate random number of a specific length?

Thanks

Comment: Please search for "Random" in the search box. This question was answered multiple times, for example here: [Secure random number generation?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/121/secure-random-number-generation)

Comment: All the links which are provided here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/124/3437 are not working.

Comment: Fixed the links